# jQuery Toggle Opacity On Click Using CSS Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm probably just retarded, but I can't seem to get this to work. All I'm trying to do is make it so when you click something (In this case, `#register`), it changes a few lines of css.

I want to make it so when you click it once, it appears, then if you click it again, it will disappear. I wrote this, and when you first click it, it will show it, but when you click it again, it won't disappear. I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. XD Thank you for any help you can give :P

### My Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#registerButton').click(function () {
        if ($("#register").css("opacity") === ".9") {
            $("#register").css({
                "opacity": "0"
            });
            $("#register").css({
                "height": "0px"
            });
        }

        if ($("#register").css("opacity") === "0") {
            $("#register").css({
                "opacity": ".9"
            });
            $("#register").css({
                "height": "260px"
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT:** I'm trying to use it this way so I can make some nice looking `css animations`, so just using the `toggle function` wouldn't work :(

Comment: Have you used `console.log()` or the debugger to see what actual value is returned from `.css()` for the opacity?

Comment: `.css()` returns the value as *string* but with a leading zero `0.9`. BTW, it may return something like `"0.8999999761581421"`

Comment: I'm assuming you're using jQuery, so why not just use [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)? Much easier IMO...

Comment: take a look if its not entering in both ifs and keeping visible

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Option 1

If you want to just toggle it hidden/visible you could just do

```
$('#registerButton').on('click', function()
{
    $('#register').toggle();
});
```

### Option 2

If you want to use CSS animations you can use `toggleClass` like this;

```
$('#registerButton').on('click', function()
{
    $('#register').toggleClass('show hide');
});
```

And then add your css selectors like this

```
.show
{
    display: block;
    height: 260px;
}

.hide
{
    display: none;
    height:0;
}
```

### Option 3

Using if statements checking opacity

```
$('#registerButton').on('click', function()
{
  var register = $('#register');

  // register is not visible lets make it visible.
  if(register.css('opacity') === '0')
  {
    register.css({
      'opacity': '0.9',
      'height': '260px'
    });
  }
  else //We know the opacity is not 0 lets make it 0.
  {
    register.css({
      'opacity': '0',
      'height': '0'
    });
  }
});
```

See working fiddle of option 3 here http://jsfiddle.net/rnhV5/

Comment: +1 While this doesn't solve the base issue of the `if` statements not working, for OP's application, I think this is a much better way of doing things...

Comment: I have some css animation effects on there. Would they still work using that?

Comment: @user2395132 See option 2 of my answer this will allow for CSS animations/ transitions.

Comment: @user2395132 I have just added an 3rd option if you would like to see how you could make it work your original way, though i would suggest using option 1 as it is the most efficient for your task.

Comment: The opacity option (#3) works great when I want to click directly on an element to "hide" or "unhide" it.  Thanks!